# Writing logs on remote server with rsyslog

Tags: debian, remote, rsyslog, remote-management, rsyslogd

I am trying to configure my firewall to write logs on a Virtual machine (Debian, bridged adapter). I've managed it to work, however, all messages going to `/var/log/messages`, if I don't explicitly filter them.

My goal is to have two different locations, like `/var/log` where will be stored logs from Virtual machine, and something like `/var/log/firewall` where I will store all logs from firewall machine, auth, firewall filters, etc.

Is it possible to achieve this?

This is my current setup:

Firewall:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf


*.* @192.168.1.5:514 # virtual machine
```

Virtual machine:

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf

    $ModLoad imudp
    $UDPServerRun 514
cron.*              /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log
:msg, contains,  "SSH"      /var/log/firewall-ssh.log
:msg,contains, "INVALID"    /var/log/firewall-invalid.log
```

Comment: Without you including a message from the firewall, and/or detailing how the firewall is configured as the priority levels, it might get difficult to answer you. True, you can always select input via the IP address, however I would advise detailing more the situation on the side of the fw.